# How to programmatically add value to GeneralField in SiteCore

Tags: sitecore

We are trying to programmatically add values to SiteCore. One of the fields is a GeneralLink. We have uploaded an executable file and trying to link that file to this GeneralLink field. But it is not working. Through the SiteCore Editor, if we choose the 'Insert Link' and select the executable file (in the media library), it is working.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Link to via via C# or via the CMS itself?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to do the field update?

Answer (score 4):

Found out the answer to the above question. Below is the code snippet.

```
// Create the media item 

MediaItem mediaItem = mediaCreator.CreateFromFile(fileName, mediaCrtrOptions);

// Create the internal link

Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField link = newItem.Fields[fieldName];

// this should be your complete media library path

link.Url = mediaItem.MediaPath;

link.LinkType = "internal";

link.Target = "";

link.TargetID = mediaItem.ID;
```

This worked for us. Hope it will help few more who are in need of this.